# FORM Login not working with Anchor #

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have the following form submit code

```
<div class="top-links">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Sign In</a>
            <div class="top-link-section">
                <form id="top-login" role="form" action="">
                    <div class="input-group" id="top-login-username">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group" id="top-login-password">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group" id="top-login-remember">
                      <label><input type="checkbox" value="yes" name="remember_me">&nbsp; Remember me</label>
                    </div>

                    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block" type="submit">Sign In</button>

                </form>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

If the user does not click on any anchor link in the page before sign in, then the form login works fine.

**Working fine**

```
 http://example.com/index.php
```

However, if the page url become something like (with anchor # behind the url address)

```
http://example.com/index.php#
```

as I got some links that is of

```
<a href="#">Events</a>
```

If user click Events to see some popup before they login, the login form **will not work**, How do I handle such scenario to ensure login still proceed even with #  at the url address.

--
Assume after login always goes back to

**example.com/index.php** but I prefer if it can be **example.com** without the index.php

Comment: why not use `href="javascript:void(0);"` to avoid  `#`?

Comment: As you have already used it...

Comment: create  a pop `div` and put your form inside that `div`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If below code puts # at the end of the page then you can make it to return false to do nothing when user clicks on this click and just open the popup.

`<a href="#">Events</a>`

You can use pure JS or jQuery to achive the same.
 So modify the HTML of those elements like this,

```
<a href="#" onclick="return eventClickBtn();">Events</a> <!-- for plain JS --> 
<a href="#" class="eventCommonBtn">Events</a> <!-- for plain jQuery -->
```

At **JS** side you need to add following:

```
<script>
function eventClickBtn() {
    // Your logic to open popupbox
    return false;
}

// For jQuery
$('.eventClickBtn').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

> By using `event.preventDefault();` default action of the event will
>   not be triggered, same goes for plain **JS**. If you return false it won't fire up the hyperlink mentioned in `href`